# Solving the partial differential equation $f_{xy}=\frac{-e^x\sin{y}+e^y\sin{x}}{\phantom{-}e^x\cos{y}+e^y\cos{x}}$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, problem-solving

> How could we evaluate this indefinite double integral in the variables $x$ and $y$?
> $$\iint \frac{-e^x\sin{y}+e^y\sin{x}}{\phantom{-}e^x\cos{y}+e^y\cos{x}}dxdy$$

The argument of the double integral must be the derivative of a $y=f(x)$ function; being this quite strange, I think that in the double integration the $y$ could simplify.

For what a double integral is, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704186/indefinite-double-integral?rq=1).

> In other words, what are the solutions $f$ to the following PDE?
>
> $$f_{xy}=\frac{-e^x\sin{y}+e^y\sin{x}}{\phantom{-}e^x\cos{y}+e^y\cos{x}}$$

Comment: What does a double indefinite integral mean?

Comment: it is the antiderivative of a two variable function

Comment: What does "antiderivative of a two variable function" mean?

Comment: The argument of the double integral must be the derivative of a y=f(x) function

Comment: Since it is quite strange, I think that in the double integration the y could simplify

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704186/indefinite-double-integral?rq=1

Comment: Since this is an unknown concept, it would be best if that link were included in the question!

Comment: alright, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Instead of phrasing the question in terms of rather nonstandard concept, why not simply ask for the solutions $f$ of the PDE $f_{xy}=\dots$?

Comment: I would try switching the coordinates to $u=x+iy, v=x-iy$.