# When can we affirm this equality about integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose we have $f(x) = \int G(x_{0},x_{1},...)\,dx_{0}\,dx_{1}\dotsb dx_{n}$
When can we affirm that $$df = G(x_{0},x_{1},...)? \tag1$$
Basically, I am having trouble to understand how to deal with differentials of functions, intuitively I thought that we can do that:

$$\delta f(x) = \int \sum\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial dx_{i}}\right)\,dx_{0}\,dx_{1}
\dotsb dx_{n} \tag2$$

But I am not sure how $(2)$ reduces to $(1)$.

Comment: Formatting note:  you can use `\tag1`, `\tag2` etc. to number equations.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704186/indefinite-double-integral.

Comment: You cannot get $(1)$ from the original equation. In fact the original equation is somewhat odd since LHS has a single independent variable but RHS has $n+1.$ Anyway, assuming I understand what you mean, let us consider the two variable case for simplicity. So let $$f(x,y)=\iint G(x,y) dx dy.$$ Then we have that $f_y=\int H(x,y)dx,$ so that $$f_{yx}=F(x,y).$$

Comment: @Allawonder Hello, thank you for the correction. Just to make sure, how is H and F in your equations related to the initial G?

Comment: @LSS Looking at the equations again, I didn't need to introduce the new symbols $H, F.$ It suffices to note that if $$f(x, y)=\iint G(x, y)dx dy,$$ then differentiating twice gives $$f_{yx}=G(x, y).$$

Answer (score 1):

In some notations this is true; for example, the volume element can be written $dV=A \ du \ dv$ for some $A$. In the case of your integral, the proper way of dealing with it is probably $df=Gdx_0dx_1\cdots dx_{n-1}dx_n$, for which its usefulness depends on the context.