# Antiderivative of multiple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I was going through the Wikipedia page of multiple integrals (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral) and noted that it states that antiderivative is only valid for single variable integrals. I was interested to know
**Why can't we apply concept of antiderivative to multiple integral?**

This Wikipedia page was where I first read about this topic and don't have sufficient knowledge regarding it so would request an explanation for naives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indefinite double integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704186/indefinite-double-integral)

Comment: Thanks, the links were helpful and they cleared my doubt.